# Voting limit conflicts with remaining votes for the day

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, waffles

You're on. You play fast and loose with the votes because, hey, it's all for the good of the community anyway. It's not like your opinion or expertise in knowing what's right or good doesn't matter. It's all about you. Voting is voting, and it's all about spreading the ajax-clicky love.

And then you get the warning some time during the day that, whoa there, Frank! You're down to your last ten, make them count. Or at least count them as they tick to zero.

And then you see a comment that makes you cut your lip, it's just that kind of night/day/afternoon/boiler room. You know what? That's going to be a comment to up vote.

But no so fast there, Jack, you don't actually have any votes left. Not for questions. Not for answers. Certainly not for comments.

[image: votes no]

And then you ask yourself, which is it? Nine votes left, or no votes at all?

Answer: None. Apparently.

#### Want to try and play the game yourself?

Vote as you would a normal course of the day, keeping an eye on a comment that you like, but not quite yet. You want to tease out the courtship, too quick and the chase is gone. When you get the note that you only have 10 votes left, look sharp! Game time.

Next, go to the comment you wanted to upvote previously, but you were too muddled in your head because of social norms and the warring families were too strong. But love won in the end and you say, dammit, an upvote for witticism!

Vote on the question or an answer it belongs to, let's hope you've got that up your sleeve. Up or down, you slide how you want. You now have nine votes left for the day.

Then vote on the comment. Now you have none.

So, Quincy, is this a bug?

Here's the browser: Opera 9.64 (yes, yes, had to be Opera huh?) on Windows.

Comment: (-1) for frenetic and hard to follow rehetorical style. Except that I've run out of votes today.

Comment: @devinb Agreed, asker is rambling where some one could just edit the entire body to be an exact copy of the title and be done with it. It's a new day again, apply the downvote accordingly please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Comment voting has its own limitations. Voting up comments is not the same as voting up questions and answers. It is entirely plausible that you would run through your comment upvotes at a different time than your normal question and answer votes.

Comment: Always thought they ran on the same counter, maybe not 30 a day, but the comments being slices of a normal vote. Maybe not.

Comment: Nope. They are on different counters. I want to say they are both 30 a day, but I can never remember exact numbers in terms of vote limits. I do know that often times during long discussions I will completely run through my comment votes and still have plenty of regular votes remaining.

Comment: That's a bother, it's a little hard to keep track of two sets of vote pockets.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure why we have such a relatively low number of comment votes to give, honestly. I would be much more comfortable in the 50+ range allowance instead. At least then I wouldn't have to feel like I need to count my votes on comments.

Comment: I love you Welbog. Where would I be without you in my life?

Comment: You'd be dispossessive, that's where you'd be.

Comment: I wish i could up-vote edits. But then, i'd just run out of those too...

Answer (score 5):

post votes and comment votes are two different pools and are tracked totally independently.

both are limited per-day.